# android ndk error "no such file or directory"?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some header files in include folder.
Here is the Android.mk file contents.

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := fpdfembedsdk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FoxitEMBSDK_EMBJavaSupport.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -g -L. -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_LDLIBS += libfpdfemb_android.a
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
  $ /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/ndk-build
Compile++ thumb  : fpdfembedsdk <= FoxitEMBSDK_EMBJavaSupport.cpp
jni/FoxitEMBSDK_EMBJavaSupport.cpp:9:21: fatal error: fs_base.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:255: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/fpdfembedsdk/FoxitEMBSDK_EMBJavaSupport.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/fpdfembedsdk/FoxitEMBSDK_EMBJavaSupport.o] Error 1
```

can anybody pls help me?

Comment: I'm curious... what problem are you trying to solve by going the mk file route rather than just using eclipse's (or whatever IDe you use) default Android compilation process?

Comment: dint get what you are trying to say

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: He is trying to compile the Foxit SDK for viewing (etc) PDF files. This SDK is NDK based, it's not like he has a choice.

Comment: Your header files should not be in a subdirectory of the include folder.

Comment: @Hitendra i am also facing the same issue, can you please share, if you have the solution for it.

Comment: @praveenSharma I just hit the same issue. If you're following the android readme they packaged with the examples, and you copied the header files into the include directory, leaving them in their folder, either change LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) to be LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../include/header_files or copy the header files out to the directory your make file is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
```

Check that. I guess you pass the wrong path. Are you sure all headers are there?